# Putting sql result set into JList

Tags: java, sql, swing, resultset, jlist

I'm working on my second year project and I'm nearly finished, but I've got a problem.

I have a table set up in Oracle that holds user names, recipients, and messages.

I wanted to make a contacts list for sending messages that would take the user names and put them into a swing jlist but i cant figure out how.

I thought maybe if I put the usernames into an array from the SQL it'd be easier but that didn't work. Any ideas?

---

Just to update, I already connected to the database.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to connect to a database, then read data from it, then massage the result into JList.

To connect to oracle from Java you need to use JDBC, tutorial for which is conveniently located here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html.

Then once you have the data, you need to put this into a `JList`, which has `setListData` method, which will do all the magic. While iterating over the data from JDBC you just need to make sure you're putting the output of your SQL query into a `Vector`, documented here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html.

Comment: never heard of the setlist data method but it sounds ike its what i need. gonna check now. ive already conected to the database and created the Jlist.

never used vectores before. 

i would paste some code to view but theres way too much

Comment: sorry vectors just arent workin for me. its gotten even more complicated now.

Comment: You could use a List instead, such as an ArrayList - which follows the Collections framework and is sometimes easier for people to understand.

Comment: @aperkins that sounds much more doable. arrays i get.

i dont get why this is giving me so much trouble. all i want is a simple list of strings from an sql table. now its spaghettti :S

Comment: @0vertone: ArrayList and Vector are effectively the same thing (although Vector is thread safe, unlike ArrayList).  The Collections framework is designed to be used with collections of things - and to make the ideas of array lists, linked lists, sets maps and the like to be easily accessible within the Java framework.